# Pasar de texto a formato ASCII y luego a binario en Python

Tags: python, string, ascii, binario

Modificar mi código para que me dé el binario de la palabra "PELOTA"

```
class Solution:
    """String -> ASCII -> binary"""
    def transform(self, stringToTransform):
      for n in stringToTransform:
         numero = ord(n)
         binario = format(numero, '08b')
         return binario
stringToTransform = "PELOTA"
print(Solution().transform(stringToTransform))
```

Me debería de salir 010100000100010101001100010011110101010001000001 que es la palabra "PELOTA" en binario, pero solo me sale el valor de la primera letra "P"
Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: "Intenté con todo" ¿podrías poner el código de alguno de tus intentos y explicar qué falló?

Comment: Si iteras por una cadena, cada iteración te da un carácter. El código ascii de un carácter lo obtienes con `ord(caracter)`, y es un entero. La representación binaria de un entero puedes obtenerla con `bin(entero)` y te dará una cadena (que comienza por "0b" cosa que probablemente querrás eliminar), o también con `"{:b}".format(entero)`, en cuyo caso el resultado ya no comenzará por 0b. Creo que con esto tienes suficiente información como para armar tú solo la solución

Comment: Para evitar que trabajemos de más, agrega cual sería el resultado correcto para la palabra que indicas.

Comment: El error de tu codigo es que retornas el valor en la primera iteracion. Tienes que tener una variable en la que vayas juntando los valores de todas las iteraciones.

Comment: Cómo haría eso? @Pablochaches tendría que crear un bucle que junte los valores?

Comment: Creas una variable antes del bucle. Lo sumas a esa variable. Y terminas retornando esta variable.

Comment: @GabinoS.U. El bucle ya lo tienes, sólo que lo abandonas en la primera iteración porque tienes un `return` dentro del bucle. Lo que debes hacer es ir acumulando los valores que va tomando `binario` en otra variable, por ejemplo en una cadena que puedes llamar `resultado`, inicialmente vacía. Dentro del bucle harías `resultado+=binario`, y cuando termines el bucle harías un `return resultado`

Comment: Ayaaa, ahora lo entiendo, tendría que poner una variable vacía para poder ir sumándola al ejecutar el bucle, ahora si ya lo entendí.
No se me vino a la mente ponerlo así, porque al retornarlo con "binario += format()" me salía error en la consola. En verdad muchas gracias¡¡ :D

Comment: Gracias @abulafia  , perdona por no entender en un principio, recién estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación, espero no haberlos incomodado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si sea adecuado hacer esta respuesta, ya que en los comentarios te hicieron ver cual era tu error. El cual es que retornas la variable en la primera iteracion, mas no la acumulas, lo puedes hacer asi

```py
class Solution:
    """String -> ASCII -> binary"""
    def transform(self, string):
      binary = "" #aqui se guardara todo
      for n in string:
         numero = ord(n)
         #con esto añadimos la cadena obtenidad a la variable antes declarada
         binary += format(numero, '08b') 
      #retornamos el valor despues de haber terminado el ciclo
      return binary
```

**Probamos**

```
string = "PELOTA"
solution = Solution().transform(string)

#imprimimos
print(solution)
#salida -> 010100000100010101001100010011110101010001000001

#aqui hacemos una comparacion, no es necesario pero asi puedes saber si el resultado es correcto
print(solution == "010100000100010101001100010011110101010001000001")
#salida -> True
```

**Convertir de binario a texto**
Para volver a convertirlo a texto hacemos el proceso inverso, ¿pero como convertimos **Toda la cadena binaria** a texto?, pues sencillo, cada letra genera una cadena de 8 dígitos, por lo que podemos convertir el texto de 8 en 8.

```py
    ...
    def destransform(self, binary) -> str:
        texto = "" #Aqui se almacenara cada letra
        #el ciclo for admite un 3°er parametro que es el numero de caracteres que tomara en cada iteracion
        for b in range(0, len(binary), 8):
          #el inicio sera 0, 8, 16 etc, y el fin sera lo que sea b + 8 que son los caracteres que vamos a convertir 
          ini,fin = b, b+8 
          binario = binary[ini:fin]
          #como esta en binario lo transformamos a un entero Ascii
          #se indica el valor y luego la base, por defecto es 10(decimal)
          valor = int(binario,2) #le ponemos base 2(binario)
          texto += chr(valor) #convertimos el valor Ascii a texto
        return texto #cuando finalize el for nos devuelve el resultado
```

**Probamos**

```py
#primero transformamos
string = "PELOTA"
solution = Solution().transform(string)
#salida -> 010100000100010101001100010011110101010001000001

#luego volvemos a String
sol = Solution().destransform(solution)
print(sol)
#salida -> PELOTA
```

Comment: Está bien hacerlo mientras se aclare el problema puntual del usuario, que en este caso es la acumulación como se le dijo varias veces. De todos modos es más prudente esperar a que haga caso a los comentarios antes de darle toda la solución.

Comment: Iba a editar mi respuestra agregando la forma contrario de conversion, igual lo agrego? o espero al OP?

Comment: Cosa tuya socio, no es obligacion hacerme caso XD

Comment: Gracias @Christian perdona por no entenderlo al inicio, recién estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación :D

Comment: @GabinoS.U. no te preocupes todos empezamos asi, agregue la funcion para hacerlo viceversa

Comment: @Christian gracias, lo voy a poner en práctica y a estudiarlo bien :D

Comment: @GabinoS.U si la respuesta resolvió tu problema se recomienda aceptarla, así se sabrá que la respuesta fue de ayuda y podrá solucionar los problemas de los demás en un futuro